# Gaussian mixture modeling with mle2/optim

Tags: r, mle

I have an `mle2` model that I've developed here just to demonstrate the problem. I generate values from two separate Gaussian distributions `x1` and `x2`, combine them together to form `x=c(x1,x2)`, and then create an MLE that attempts to re-classify `x` values as belonging to the left of a specific `x` value or the right of a specific `x` value via the `xsplit` paremeter.

The problem is that the parameters found are not ideal. Specifically, `xsplit` is always returned as whatever its starting value is. And if I change its starting value (e.g., as 4 or 9) there are huge differences in the log likelihood that results.

Here is the completely reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1001)
library(bbmle)
x1 = rnorm(n=100,mean=4,sd=0.8)
x2 = rnorm(n=100,mean=12,sd=0.4)
x = c(x1,x2)
hist(x,breaks=20)
ff = function(m1,m2,sd1,sd2,xsplit) {
  outs = rep(NA,length(xvals))
  for(i in seq(1,length(xvals))) {
    if(xvals[i]<=xsplit) {
      outs[i] = dnorm(xvals[i],mean=m1,sd=sd1,log=T)
    }
    else {
      outs[i] = dnorm(xvals[i],mean=m2,sd=sd2,log=T)
    }
  }
  -sum(outs)
}

# change xsplit starting value here to 9 and 4
# and realize the difference in log likelihood
# Why isn't mle finding the right value for xsplit?
mo = mle2(ff,
          start=list(m1=1,m2=2,sd1=0.1,sd2=0.1,xsplit=9), 
          data=list(xvals=x))

#print mo to see log likelihood value
mo

#plot the result
c=coef(mo)
m1=as.numeric(c[1])
m2=as.numeric(c[2])
sd1=as.numeric(c[3])
sd2=as.numeric(c[4])
xsplit=as.numeric(c[5])
leftx = x[x<xsplit]
rightx = x[x>=xsplit]
y1=dnorm(leftx,mean=m1,sd=sd1)
y2=dnorm(rightx,mean=m2,sd=sd2)
points(leftx,y1*40,pch=20,cex=1.5,col="blue")
points(rightx,y2*90,pch=20,cex=1.5,col="red")
```

How can I modify my mle2 to capture the correct parameters, specifically for `xsplit`?

Comment: for what it's worth, this is an optimization problem rather than specifically an `mle2` problem; `mle2` just wraps the `optim` function.  Mixture models are **notoriously** hard to fit -- there are many special-purpose optimization algorithms developed for them.

Comment: if mle2 wraps the optim function, then I don't see why it explains how this is failing, because under the hood, it's doing optim.

Comment: Would it be easier to start by using `nls` to fit to a function of the sort `a1*exp(-x^2/b1) + a2*exp(-x^2/b2)` and then classify data by the relative amplitudes of those two gaussians?  (Of course this won't work well when the Rayleigh criterion is not well met)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mixture models present a lot of technical challenges (symmetry under relabeling of components, etc.); unless you have very specific needs, you might be better off using one of the large number of special-purpose mixture modeling packages that have been written for R (just `library("sos"); findFn("{mixture model}")` or `findFn("{mixture model} Gaussian")`).

However, in this case, you have a more specific problem, which is that the goodness-of-fit/likelihood surface of the `xsplit` parameter is "bad" (i.e. the derivative is zero almost everywhere).  In particular, if you consider a pair of points `x1`, `x2` in your data set that are neighbours, the likelihood is exactly the same for any splitting parameter between `x1` and `x2` (because any of those values splits the data set into the same two components).  That means the likelihood surface is piecewise flat, which makes it almost impossible for any sensible optimizer -- even those such as Nelder-Mead that don't explicitly depend on derivatives.  Your choices are (1) use some sort of brute-force stochastic optimizer (such as method="SANN" in optim()); (2) take `xsplit` out of your function and profile over it (i.e. for each possible choice of `xsplit`, optimize over the other four parameters); (3) smooth your splitting criterion (i.e. fit a logistic probability of belonging to one component or the other); (4) use a special-purpose mixture model fitting algorithm, as recommended above.

```
set.seed(1001)
library(bbmle)
x1 = rnorm(n=100,mean=4,sd=0.8)
x2 = rnorm(n=100,mean=12,sd=0.4)
x = c(x1,x2)
```

Your `ff` function can be written more compactly:

```
## ff can be written more compactly:
ff2 <- function(m1,m2,sd1,sd2,xsplit) {
    p <- xvals<=xsplit
    -sum(dnorm(xvals,mean=ifelse(p,m1,m2),
               sd=ifelse(p,sd1,sd2),log=TRUE))
}

## ML estimation
mo <- mle2(ff2,
           start=list(m1=1,m2=2,sd1=0.1,sd2=0.1,xsplit=9), 
           data=list(xvals=x))

## refit with a different starting value for xsplit
mo2 <- update(mo,start=list(m1=1,m2=2,sd1=0.1,sd2=0.1,xsplit=4))

## not used here, but maybe handy
plotfun <- function(mo,xvals=x,sizes=c(40,90)) {
    c <- coef(mo)
    hist(xvals,col="gray")
    p <- xvals <= c["xsplit"]
    y <- with(as.list(coef(mo)),
              dnorm(xvals,mean=ifelse(p,m1,m2),
                    sd=ifelse(p,sd1,sd2))*sizes[ifelse(p,1,2)])
    points(xvals,y,pch=20,cex=1.5,col=c("blue","red")[ifelse(p,1,2)])
}

plot(slice(mo),ylim=c(-0.5,10))
plot(slice(mo2),ylim=c(-0.5,10))
```

I cheated a little bit to extract just the `xsplit` parameter:

Likelihood surface around `xsplit=9`:

[image: xsplit=9]

Likelihood surface around `xsplit=4`:

[image: xsplit=4]

Also see [p. 243 of Bolker 2008](http://books.google.ca/books?id=flyBd1rpqeoC&pg=PA243&dq=bolker+discontinuities+thresholds&hl=en&sa=X&ei=khn1Usm7MqLcyQGC34A4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bolker%20discontinuities%20thresholds&f=false).

**Update: smoothing**

As I mentioned above, one solution is to make the boundary between the two mixture components smooth, or gradual, rather than sharp.  I used a logistic function `plogis()` with midpoint at `xsplit` and a scale arbitrarily set to 2 (you could try to make it sharper; in principle you could make it an adjustable parameter, but if you do that you'll probably run into trouble again because the optimizer may want to make it infinite ...) In other words, rather that saying that all observations with `x<xsplit` are *definitely* in component 1 and all observations with `x>xsplit` are *definitely* in component 2, we say that observations that are equal to `xsplit` have a 50/50 probability of falling in either component, with the certainty of being in component 1 increasing as `x` decreases below `xsplit`.  A logistic function with a very large scaling parameter approximates the sharp-split model previously attempted; generally you want to make the scaling parameter "large enough" to get a reasonable split and small enough not to run into numeric problems. (If you make the scale too large, the computed probabilities will underflow/overflow to 0 or 1 and you'll be back where you started...)

This is my second or third try; I had to do considerable fiddling (bounding values away from 0, or between 0 and 1, and fitting the standard deviations on a log scale), but the results seem reasonable. If I don't use `clamp()` on the logistic (`plogis`) function then I get 0 or 1 probabilities; if I don't use `clamp()` (one-sided) on the Normal probabilities then they can underflow to zero -- in either case I get infinite or `NaN` outcomes.  Fitting the standard deviations on the log scale works better because one doesn't run into problems when the optimizer tries negative values for the standard deviation ...

```
 ## bound x values between lwr and upr
 clamp <- function(x,lwr=0.001,upr=0.999) {
     pmin(upr,pmax(lwr,x))
 }

 ff3 <- function(m1,m2,logsd1,logsd2,xsplit) {
     p <- clamp(plogis(2*(xvals-xsplit)))
     -sum(log((1-p)*clamp(dnorm(xvals,m1,exp(logsd1)),upr=Inf)+
                  p*clamp(dnorm(xvals,m2,exp(logsd2)),upr=Inf)))
 }
 xvals <- x
 ff3(1,2,0.1,0.1,4)                                 
 mo3 <- mle2(ff3,
           start=list(m1=1,m2=2,logsd1=-1,logsd2=-1,xsplit=4), 
           data=list(xvals=x))
 ## Coefficients:
 ##          m1          m2      logsd1      logsd2      xsplit 
 ##  3.99915532 12.00242510 -0.09344953 -1.13971551  8.43767997
```

The results look reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I think I am beginning to understand. You mentioned one option (3) is to smooth the fitting criterion. I'm not sure how I would do that, nor do I fully understand what you mean. Would you mind implementing that for this example?

Comment: Would you mind commenting this code a bit? For example, I've never heard of a function pmax or pmin and just trying to understand what your "clamp" function does? What was the idea behind the the logistic function?

Comment: Additionally, why use logSD rather than SD?